# Open application when notification is clicked

Tags: android, push-notification

> Hi! I am having android code for simple push notification. Its working fine but when I am clicking on message in notification my application is not opening.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
Notification notification;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ed3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tittle = ed1.getText().toString().trim();
            String subject = ed2.getText().toString().trim();
            String body = ed3.getText().toString().trim();

            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(String.valueOf(MainActivity.this));
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(tittle)
                    .setContentText(subject)
                    .setSubText(body);

            notification = builder.build();
            manager.notify(0, notification);
        }
    });
}
```

}

> Help me to fix it

Answer (score 4):

Use Intent and and pass intent in pending intent.and also use PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT instead of 0 on 
Constructor of Pending intent.

```
 Intent myintent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 2):

create object of `Intent` before creating `PendingIntent`

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.this);
```

and then pass it to `PendingIntent`

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, 0);
```

Comment: I need one more functionality in my application that how can i make a push notification to display every morning

Comment: Please guide me if you have any idea

Comment: @SivaKumar If it helps, accept it as answer and your other query is not related to this question so ask another question.